OSM - dynamical vectorLayers from a loop
i'm working on addon for the cms WebsiteBaker to display osm-maps. i'm using categories, every category is a layer on the map. For the output, i use a twig-template. all datas come's from the database, loaded via PHP in a array, called "CatMarkerList", a simple multidimensional array with cats and markers. Every marker has the possibility, to display a popup-window with additional informations like title, lon & lat etc, everybody know's that.
my code to activate the control-function
var controls = {
        selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([ 
            {% for cat in CatMarkerList %}
                vectorLayer{{ loop.index }},
            {% endfor %}
        ], { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };

i'm using here ol 2.13, but have also a script with the latest ol-version, works like this, so it doesnt matter.
Everything works in a single output in the cms (WebsiteBaker), but my target is a output in multiple sections, means: more than one map on a single page.
So i put the js-code from my twig-template into a js-file, change the php-arrey into a json-object.
Everything works again in a single-layer-output, but if i've more than one categories (or layers), i lost the controls.
for example: layer-name is "vectorLayer" + the cat-id, so vectorLayer8, vectorLayer9 etc
my problem: i've only one working variant - if i write the layernames hardcoded in the lines, see example
var controls = {
        selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([ 
            vectorLayer8, vectorLayer9, vectorLayer10
        ], { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
    };

every other solution will not work
what i'm trying:
-add a empty array "vectorList" at the begin, then i read the json-object and add for every category the layer-name this this array and using this new array instead of the comma-separated layer-list from the example - but doesn't work
-change the new array to a string (isString), console.log give me the correct output, but doesn't work

a loop inside my code, based of the lenght from my vectorList, to add the layer-name - not possible on this place

only chance: a hardcoded layer-list on this place
i can declare my addon  as "for-single-section-use only", so that it work, but that's not my target. I spend a lot of hours in the last week, but dont found a solution and i dont found any examples in the web, where you work with dynamical layernames
i'm sure, everbody see it: i'm not a JS-Expert. i can read and understand the codes and i have the time, to search the web and learn more and more, but i think, i need some help here
